# Notification on new Email with Android

Tags: android, email, notifications

is there a way for an app to get notified when a new email has been received? My goal is, to rise an alert (play a sound, vibrate, whatever) if an email with a specific topic gets received (think of it like an "filter" or a "rule"), but I dont want to check the email server by myself. I think I'm searching for something like  "android.telephony.PhoneStateListener" but for Email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry there is no general concept of "new email."  Gmail has its own email database and management, the email app has another, and other email apps may have their own.

And there is certainly no "email server" associated with the telephony subsystem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I was afraid that email is not "deep" integrated in the system.

Comment: There must be a way to do it, but may be not by querying the gmail client, but by querying the gmail account itself.  i know it is possible; look up Gmail Unread Count in the market.  If it can tell you how many e-mails are unread, it will know when the number goes up also.