# New Email Notification in android

Tags: android, email, notifications

I need to create the custom broadcast receiver,which notifies the arrival of new emails. That means when the new Email s received to the the already configured email account , then the intent will be fired. how can i find the arrival of new Email.I am Using Android_javamail API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. There are no documented and supported broadcast `Intents` for Gmail. There are no broadcast `Intents` for the open source Email app. Third party email clients are not obligated to support any particular broadcast `Intents`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer to your question.

See this [Notification on new Email with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252897/notification-on-new-email-with-android)

I know that Gmail sends a ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED notification when the unread count changes.

You can browse this code to see how it's used, https://github.com/jonasl/GmailNotifier