# email alert on default gmail app Android

Tags: android, gmail, alert

Is there any way by which I can set toast on when a new email comes in my gmail inbox of default android app.

I need to generate alert on my widget whenever a new email comes in my gmail inbox. "

Any help would be appreciated!?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no general concept of "new email." Gmail has its own email database and management, the email app has another, and other email apps may have their own.

And there is certainly no "email server" associated with the telephony subsystem

refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254426/2771869

Comment: Thanks but I saw an app that is using the default gmail inbox and it has a widget with a badge on it that shows the number of unread emails. Any idea about what is the concept behind that?

Comment: you can get unread email in "Gmail" but can't generate alert when new email comes.

Comment: ok and any links or answers to that ? getting the unread emails?

Answer (score 0):

ok would recommend you  to use a **JavaMail** to keep track of unreaded mails in your account ... then i would create **AlarmManager** with custom **broadcast receiver** for displaying your toast/notification ...

Comment: Yes I've also started reading posts related javaMail but then I wondered may b there is some way to get alerts on the default app.Thanks anyways

Comment: Gives me motivation. :)